# Access of Undefined Property as3

Tags: css, actionscript-3

I know there are a number of posts dealing with this issue. But, I'm still not understanding it.

I keep getting a "1120: Access of undefined property CSSloader." in the following script:

```
package as3.comp{

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.StyleSheet;


public class cont extends MovieClip {

    public var contentWidth:Number;
    public var contentHeight:Number;

    private var myXML:XML;
    private var myLoader:URLLoader;

    public function cont():void {
        //Start
    }

    public function start():void {
        myTooltip.start();
        myTooltip.followMouse(false);
        myTooltip.hide();
        myWaiting.start();
        myWaiting.hide();
        myXML = new XML();
        myXML.ignoreComments=true;
        myXML.ignoreWhitespace=true;
        contentWidth=100;
        contentHeight=100;
        contentSpace.width=contentWidth;
        contentSpace.height=contentHeight;
        //myWaiting.hide(); //hide clock
    }

    public function loadMc(contentFile:String):void {

        var pictLdr:Loader = new Loader();
        var pictURL:String=contentFile;
        var pictURLReq:URLRequest=new URLRequest(pictURL);
        pictLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imgLoadedF);
        pictLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preloader);
        pictLdr.load(pictURLReq);
        contentLoadMC.addChild(pictLdr);

    }

    private function imgLoadedF(event:Event):void {
        myTooltip.hide();
        MovieClip(parent.parent).addContentMovie(this);
        MovieClip(parent.parent).refresh();
    }

    private function preloader(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        var pcent:Number=event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal*100;
        myTooltip.show(""+int(pcent));
    }

    public function loadCSS(event:Event):void {
        var CSSloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var req_css:URLRequest = new URLRequest("example.css");
        CSSloader.load(req_css);
        CSSloader.addEventListener("complete", loadXML);
    }

    public function loadXML(contentFile:String) {
        var XML_URL:String=contentFile;
        var myXMLURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest(XML_URL);
        myLoader=new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
        myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);
    }

    private function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void {
        myXML=XML(myLoader.data);
        myXML.ignoreWhite = true;

        var sheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
        sheet.parseCSS(CSSloader.data);
        myHtmlText.styleSheet = sheet;


        myHtmlText.htmlText="HERE" + myXML.pageTop;
        myHtmlText.width=contentWidth-10;
        myHtmlText.height=myHtmlText.textHeight+30;
        myHtmlText.x=10;
        myHtmlText.y=10;
        contentSpace.width=contentWidth;
        contentSpace.height=myHtmlText.height+4;
        myWaiting.hide();
        MovieClip(parent.parent).addContentMovie(this);
        MovieClip(parent.parent).refresh();
        myLoader.removeEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);

    }

    public function loadContent(contentFile:String) {
        if (contentFile.substr(-3)=="xml") {
            myWaiting.show();//show clock
            loadXML(contentFile);
        } else {
            myTooltip.show("0");
            loadMc(contentFile);
        }
    }
}
```

}
I've tried adding the code within loadCSS to both loadXML and xmlLoaded, but get the same error.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared CSSloader in the function loadCSS, but you get the error in the function xmlloaded, which is a different scope. If you want CSSloader to be scoped for all functions, you'll have to declare it as a variable *outside* these functions - by convention at the top. (Unfortunately you have omitted the context of this code, but I assume this is inside a class?).

Comment: It is inside a class (I think. New to classes.) Here's the full as file code:

Comment: Did you try what brennan suggested? move this line `var CSSloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();` underneath this line `private var myLoader:URLLoader;` and make it private.

Comment: Ok. Did that. Not getting the error anymore. But, also not getting the css styles.

Comment: I FIXED IT!! With you guys' help. I was calling the functions in the wrong order. loadXML calls loadCSS then xmlLoaded. WHEW!  Thanks again guys.